# Can you set a method to a variable?

Tags: java

Is it possible to do something like this in Java

```
private ? /* (I dont know what Class to use) */ shortcutToMethod = redundantMethod(game.getGraphics());
```

So instead of calling `redundantMethod(game.getGraphics().doThisMethod());`

I could just do `shortCutToMethod.doThisMethod();`

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you can get a better answer if you show a longer piece of code where you want to have this.

Comment: do you know any language where it is possible?

Comment: Functional interfaces is what you are looking for. Technically they are regular interfaces, where you assign an instance of a type that implements it. Syntactically, there are some shortcuts that makes it fell like a method or function.

Comment: Did you mean `redundantMethod(game.getGraphics()).doThisMethod()`? It's hard to see how you'd specify that you want to call `doThisMethod()` on the result of `game.getGraphics()` and then call `redundantMethod` passing the result. A complete example would make it much easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: C#, C, C++, probably any except of java?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger really? can you provide example in C or C++?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

Comment: @StefanSteinegger try to write an example and you'll see function pointers do not resolve the problem.

Comment: C++ you can load a var with anything. Not only an Object, which seems to be where Java is.

Comment: you apply redundantMethod both to "game.getGraphics()" and "game.getGraphics().doThisMethod()". Is it what you really want?

Comment: `private Object shortcutToMethod = redundantMethod(game.getGraphics())` always works...

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov "do you know any language where it is possible?" Any language where function/method/procedures are first class citizens.  Scheme, Haskell, Scala, OCaml, Javascript, to name a few.

Answer (score 25):

Java 8 has introduced the idea of a Functional Interface, which allows you to essentially assign methods to variables.  It includes a number of commonly-used interfaces as well.

Common examples:

- `Consumer<T>` - a method that takes in `T` and returns `void`
- `Function<T, R>` - a method that takes in `T` and returns `R`
- `Supplier<R>` - a method that takes no arguments and returns `R`
- `Runnable` - a method that takes no arguments and returns `void`
- `Predicate<T>` - a method that takes in `T` and returns `boolean`

In your case, you appear to be after a `Runnable`:

```
Runnable shortcutToMethod = () -> redundantMethod(game.getGraphics());
shortcutToMethod.run();
```

Comment: *returns `void`* not sure if returning nothing counts as something ;)

Comment: @KamilDrakari Yup, that was rather silly of me, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 23):

In Java, there are various ways. If you take a look at `java.util.function` package, you can see

- `Function`: Takes one argument, produces one result
- `Consumer`: Takes one argument, produces nothing.
- `BiConsumer`: Takes two arguments, produces nothing.
- `Supplier`: Takes no argument, produces one result.
- `Predicate`: Boolean value function of one argument

You can used them as inputs for your method and execute it within.

Comment: Actually, this will create instances of an `Interface` instead of *linking* to the method. It might be worth also mentioning **Reflection**. Because there you can actually refer to a certain method and apply them to arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functional interfaces. A functional interface allows one to adapt an abstract method to a lambda expression that can in turn be stored in a variable, and that's close to storing a method in a variable.

There are a number of functional interfaces available in Java (you can design others yourself).  For example, if your `redundantMethod` returns nothing, you can use a functional interface appropriate for that:

```
private Consumer<Graphics> shortcutToMethod = 
           graphics -> redundantMethod(game.getGraphics());
```

It can even go with a method reference:

```
private Consumer<Graphics> shortcutToMethod = this::redundantMethod; //some rules apply
```

And that can be called with:

```
shortcutToMethod.accept(game.getGraphics());
```

`Consumer` is one of the functional interfaces that come with Java, and it declares the abstract method `accept` that is called above. There are others that you can find in the `java.util.function` package, and you choose or write a particular functional interface based on what signature your particular method has. See [java.util.function package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Well in addition to what the others already wrote. Assuming the returntype is "Graphics" here are 4 examples:

```
//You need some kind of forward declaration, name don't matter:
public static interface FunctionDeclaration{
    public Graphics doThisMethod();
}

//here you go and assing your variable
private FunctionDeclaration shortCutToMethod = game.getGraphics()::doThisMethod;
//or you want this - not sure?
// private FunctionDeclaration shortCutToMethod = game::getGraphics;
// and then you just call it:
shortCutToMethod.doThisMethod();
```

If you want to pass the graphics

```
//You need some kind of forward declaration, name don't matter:
public static interface FunctionDeclaration{
    public Graphics doThisMethod(Graphics g);
}
//assign your variable
private FunctionDeclaration shortCutToMethod = param -> param.doThisMethod();
//and call it - calls game.getGraphics().doThisMethod()
shortCutToMethod.doThisMethod(game.getGraphics());
```

If your "redundant" method does something:

```
//You need some kind of forward declaration, name don't matter:
public static interface FunctionDeclaration{
    public Graphics doThisMethod(Graphics g);
}
//assign your variable
private FunctionDeclaration shortCutToMethod = param -> redundantMethod(param.doThisMethod());
//and call it - calls redundantMethod(game.getGraphics().doThisMethod())
shortCutToMethod.doThisMethod(game.getGraphics());
```

If your redundant method does somthing without passing graphics:

```
//You need some kind of forward declaration, name don't matter:
public static interface FunctionDeclaration{
    public Graphics doThisMethod();
}
//assign your variable
private FunctionDeclaration shortCutToMethod = () -> redundantMethod(game.getGraphics().doThisMethod());
//and call it - calls redundantMethod(game.getGraphics().doThisMethod())
shortCutToMethod.doThisMethod();
```

And so on ...
Sure enough for the forward declaration you can use any existing interface like the predefined ones Joe and others mentioned(eg. Supplier).